# Slick slider to show all elements on desktop but show x amount on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, slick.js

I have a six images in my slick slider.

- On desktop (1200px +) I want to display all images in a row (which works).
- At 992px width, I want it to only display 3.

First time using slick slider so I'm unsure if this is the right approach: currently, I have one parent div which is trying to accomplish my goals, but unsure if the correct approach would be to contain two divs:

- Div 1 will show all six images in a row and then be hidden at 992px width.
- Div 2 will contain the slick slider and be shown at 992px width.

**Current approach:**

```js
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="showcaseRow py-4" align="center">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
 
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 img__container justify-content-center align-self-center">
         <div class="slider">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakepoints for responsive

```
$('.center').slick({
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 6,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 992,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```